# How to append data to file

Tags: java, android, file, java-io, fileoutputstream

Good day, I have a problem with append my datas to file, when is the method onClick() called. For example, on the first call of method I want to save to file with name mylogs.txt the text "hello ". On the second call I need to write to same file the text "world". So the final written string in my file should be the "hello world", but there is the problem, that in the file is written only "world". Thank you for your reactions and sorry for my bad english.

**onClick() method**

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String filename = editTextFileName.getText().toString();
                String data = editTextData.getText().toString();

                try {
                    File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), filename);

                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

                    myOutWriter.append(data);

                    myOutWriter.close();
                    fOut.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Comment: finally I fixed It -> http://pastebin.com/Z74tmsBZ ... sorry for useless question

Comment: `new FileOutputStream(myFile, true)`. No need to make such a mystery out of it.